# Windows 7 login screen: how change default action to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, login-screen

I know how to change default to sleep in start menu *after* logging in, but what about in the logon screen? How do I change the red button on the bottom right to default to sleeping instead of shutdown?

Comment: I don't think I've hit the sleep button in ages. I'm lucky my keyboard has a sleep button.